# How to simulate network partitions on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, iptables, firewall, windows-firewall

Working on a project which implements a clustering algorithm. One important property of the clustering is to respect guarantees when face a network partition.

To prove that clustering works I need a way to emulate partitions in my windows development environment.

In the following example i will use term node and in this context is a Tcp Listener which starts on an Ip and accepts incoming connections on a port. Ex in c#: `new TcpListener("10.16.8.9", 12345)`

Test case : N2 partitioned from N1 and N3

```
Given 
    I have a cluster of 3 nodes running on one NIC with 3 IPs
        N1 running at 10.16.8.9
        N2 running at 10.16.8.10
        N3 running at 10.16.8.11
        Dev can connect to N1, N2, N3
When 
    A partition occurrences for N2 
Then
    N2 cannot reach N1 and N3
    N1 can reach N3
    N3 can reach N1
    Dev can connect to N1, N2, N3
```

Illustrated

[image]

What are my options if I want to block/restore the traffic flow from/to N2 with the windows tooling ?

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve is a bit difficult to understand, but I'm quite sure address B and address C should not be identical.

Comment: @Massimo corrected, i want to emulate the situation when nodes cannot talk to each other due a network issue. Ex  [A] and [B,C] means, that to A all connections are dropped form B and C and at the same time A cannot reach B and C

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that on Windows if all three addresses belong to the same computer; all traffic netween them is routed internally and you can't block it.